# resizing element with jquery breaks 100% height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sidebar that has this css:

```css
  background:#164272;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:70px;
  width:250px;
  height:100%;
```

And with jquery im showing a table that by default was hidden and is only shown when clicking an element.
But when i show the element on smaller sized screens it pretty much breaks the 100% height. here's an image[image: broken 100% height]

How can i prevent it from breaking the 100%? 
Thank you

Comment: `height` does not work in `%` unit

Comment: set `top` to `0px` instead of `70px`

Answer (score 0):

Try height  100% html and body. % height relative value. So it must need standard height value. in this time html, body is the standard.

And don't forget DOCTYPE declaration.

```css
    html, body 
 {height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;}

  #yourDiv{
  background:#164272;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:70px;
  width:250px;
  height:100%;
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/under_09/4bs4r0y5/

Comment: tried this. didn't work. see the thing is the height of the html actually changes when its content changes, this is why it crops the bar

Answer (score 0):

If 100% height of the side bar is what you want at all screen resolution then why not

```
.sidebar {
   top : 0;
   bottom:0;
   left :0;
}
```

Full fledged [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/tbmbfk3j/)

please note that since your width is defined in PX , is't not exactly going to be resposive , on that note checkout [min-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp) and [max-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp).

Comment: ok the thing is the sidebar was actually already like that BUT when the white divs content gets larger than the sidebar originally was, THAT'S when the sidebar then basically crops